# Where is the official website to report bugs in ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch

There are many bugs and there're many incompleted features in ubuntu touch. Now i could do nothing but to report them and hope them can be fixed. The question is where to report them?

Answer (score 2):

[Ubuntu Avengers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers) is a page with handy links for bug filing.
 It contains bug report links and preferred bug report forms for Apps, Scopes, Indicators, Toolkit / Platform, and Web Services.

From [How to report bugs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Contribute):

> Please DO NOT file bugs at the "ubuntu-touch-preview" project. This
>   project is no longer monitored, bugs should be filed in the individual
>   affected packages. Include the steps to reproduce, an automated
>   testcase (if possible) and the frequency of the bug.
>
> Generally, please try to do your best to make sure you put enough
>   information so we can track the hardware and build, for example give
>   "mako #120" in the subject to indicate you're using a Nexus 4 and
>   image #120. You can find out what image you're running in System
>   Settings -> About.
>
> However, if you have bugs which concern the image tools
>   (ubuntu-device-flash), bug tracking is open and bugs are welcome; go
>   to https://bugs.launchpad.net/phablet-tools/+filebug to open a new
>   bug.
>
> If you want to help out with reporting or triaging bugs, that's great.
>   Ask on IRC or the mailing list if you're unsure. We've got to work all
>   together on this to make Ubuntu for Phones & Tablets truly rock!

You can also file bugs on device:

> To file a bug directly on the device use the "ubuntu-bug" program,
>   specifying the package which you'd like to report against. e.g.
>
> ```
>  adb shell 
>     ubuntu-bug unity8
> ```
>
> The above is the preferred method for filing bugs directly on the
>   device. If for some reason you are unable to run ubuntu-bug on the
>   phone, you can manually file a bug using the links given in [Avengers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Avengers). You can also
>   find existing bugs via those links.

In addition, You can also join the IRC channel `#ubuntu-touch` on [irc.freenode.net](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=ubuntu-touch) where you can get help and discus about anything.

Comment: I like the idea of using the ubuntu-bug command to report bugs, because I assume it will automatically include all the environmental data pertinent to the bug. However, how do I discover the official package-name of the apps? For example, the Music player is just labeled "Music", I doubt that's its official package-name. How would I report a bug for the "Music" app via the ubuntu-bug command?